# Can't transparent navigation bar and status bar in android

Tags: android, android-theme

I am trying to transparent navigation bar and status bar on Android 13 and below version. But getting different result.

Here what suggested in latest android dev event:

themes.xml

```
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

MainActivity.kt

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
```

[image]

But I am getting result like this in Android 13 and Android 8 version:

[image]

[image: Android 13]

[image: Android 8]

Am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: Can you upload the whole style in which those two lines are in?

Comment: <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">

        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>

</style>

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is an intended behavior. The `BottomNavigationView` is respecting the bottom navigation bar space, and the bottom navigation bar has a transparent background, it's just that the root layout has a white background.

You can either:

- Make the app full screen, so the bottom of the `BottomNavigationView` neglects the windows insets calculated by bottom navigation bar size, or...
- You can change the color of the navigation bar to match the color of the `BottomNavigationView` so it can look like one view

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue on Samsung devices. I didn't find any reasonable fix but I managed to find one workaround, instead of setting `@android:color/transparent`, make it almost transparent with `#01FFFFFF`. So it would be like this:

```
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">#01FFFFFF</item>
```